# If directory is empty do this, If directory is not empty do that

Tags: bash

So far I've got this. Is there a more efficient way?

```
if ls -1 $HOME/path/to/folder/* >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        echo Directory is not empty.
else
        echo Directory is empty.
fi
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a standard exercise in all books/blogs/manuals about shells: in bash

```
 [ "$(ls -A /path/to/directory)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
```

Bash does not have a standard test for a directory being empty, like [ -f file ], so we have to write it. The    test && then 1 || or 2 is a standard way to condense a conditional statement of the form

```
if condition is satistfied
    then do 1
else
    do 2
fi
```